# vertical-align in table cells not working when there is a floated element inside the <td>

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

This fiddle demonstrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/wrYsx/

Related code:

```
<style>
    #floater {
        background-color: red;
        height: 35px;
        width: 35px;
        float: right;
    }

    table {
        width: 100%;
    }

    table tr td {
        border: 1px solid green;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 35px;
    }
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id='floater'></div>
            some text
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            some text
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Basically, if I have a td with a given height, I can use vertical-align: middle to center things in the td.  However, when there is another element inside the td that is floated (right in my case) then the vertical-align is not respected and the text sits at the top of the td.  Any ideas how to style this so you can have a td with vertical-align and floated elements?

Also, I found this post: stackoverflow.com/questions/2641615/table-cell-doesnt-obey-vertical-align-css-declaration-when-it-contains-a-floate however it's not a solution for me, since I will likely need to have floated elements.  I've tried using positioning to mimic the same layout but it doesn't seem I can position a td cell so that I can use position: absolute inside it to position the "floated" element at right: 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding an empty element to the td.

```
<span class="vertical_aligner"></span>

.vertical_aligner {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious to know the cause to the issue and why this solution works. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioning seems to do the job. You just need to make sure you put `position:relative` on the TD.

```
#floater {
    background-color: red;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0
}

table {
    width: 100%;
}

table tr td {
    border: 1px solid green;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 35px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Table cells in firefox can't be relatively positioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `line-height` on the table cell to match the cell's height to fix this.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wrYsx/3/)**

```
table tr td {
    border: 1px solid green;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 35px;
    line-height:35px;
}
​
```

Note that this will only work in the text in the cell occupies one line.